# Реализация кривого border dashed

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как лучше реализовать данный элемент, это прослойка между двумя блоками. Вариант вставить картинкой рассматривал, он не подходит. Так же пытался сделать через частичного border на некоторых элементах и skew, но толгового из этого ничего не вышло.[image: элемент который нужно сделать]

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

#b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-top: 1px dashed #aaa;
  position: relative;
}

.sep {
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: -15px;
}

.t {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #ddd;
  border-top: 1px dashed #aaa;
  border-left: 1px dashed #aaa;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>

<div id="b">
  <div class="sep">
    <div class="t"></div>
    <div class="t"></div>
    <div class="t"></div>
    <div class="t"></div>
    <div class="t"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```